# Float and expand problems

Tags: html, css, expand

I'm not an experienced html coder, all of it was done without any professional help so the results look quirky.
The web site: www.cakery.co.il/beta
I have float and expand problems (as Dreamweaver states) - when I enter my site and try to resize the window, the top (blue) ribbon and the bottom ones are cut off and look weird.

How can I fix this?

For example, this is the top ribbon code in the css:

```
#blue_decoration {
    height: 85px;
    background-image: url(_images/top_stripe.png);
}
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what's happening. What browser are you using?

Comment: The behavior is normal..

Comment: If you 'restore down' the window and scroll vertically you'll see the cut off ribbons. I use IE9. View this page using your iPhone and you'll see it more clearly.

Comment: This is what I see: http://tinypic.com/r/29mozle/6 and this http://tinypic.com/r/suu8af/6

Comment: The cut off part is on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Yes, but on the top right corner the blue ribbon does not continue to repeat itself and also cuts off.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to exactly see what the problem is without seeing the rest of what's going on but I can nevertheless give some pointers.

I'll PM the link if you like, but you can as easily copy paste the following to see for yourself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />        
<title></title>
    <style>
    #blue_decoration {
        height: 85px;
        background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Air_Force_Good_Conduct_Medal_ribbon.png');
    }
    #bottom_blue_decoration {
        height: 30%;
        background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/Air_Force_Good_Conduct_Medal_ribbon.png');
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header id="blue_decoration"> Hello World</header><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<footer id="bottom_blue_decoration"> don't collapse me! </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

You might notice that it repeats across the screen without many problems. However, there are no positions related to the styling as such; rather it is dependent on content not to collapse. It might be better, to say, specify top and bottom positioning. Another thing is that you are probably reusing ids - which should, strictly speaking, be used only once on a given page. This is easy enough to fix - just specify that piece of styling as a class (using a dot instead of a hash) and call it using the keyword class instead of id.

Try experimenting using non-absolute values for the background size, but instead responsive percentages. A significant question is: do you want any content to cover this background? If you want it to be an image without any content you may ultimately be better off using an `<img>` tag...

Comment: This looks good as it doesn't collapse. I'll give it a try when I get back home and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: I'm having difficulties with this. I tried changing values around, couldn't fix the problem. Are you able to help if you look at the code? You can see the site here: www.cakery.co.il/b3 (the css file is called styles.css)

Comment: I don't offhand see anyhing visibly wrong on your site (just one or two unrelated pointers though; probably should have the javascript at the bottom of the file, and also have title attributes for the image navigation buttons). What is it that you are seeing that doesn't look right?

Comment: Wait, I see what you mean in IE (it's always IE, isn't it?) - I'd advise using an IE specific stylesheet to be triggered with an [if ie] statement that will add an additional margin.

Comment: Take a look at the two images I posted above. You can see the top blue header and both ribbons below being cut off if you resize the browser window (this happens on all browsers, not just IE). Is there a solution for this?